# Can't understand the 指すもの for それ

Tags: translation

What is それ in 「俺もそれを強制しないようにしている。」? I think that the author says something like this - "...and I'm trying to not force her to do it(しっかりとした料理) too." Also is it correct to think that 「めんどくさい」 is saying the sister of author, who doesn't want to cook?

> 普段は８割くらいジャンクフードやカップラーメンのみで構成されているウチの食卓なのに、今日は珍しくしっかりとした料理を作ってるみたいだ。いつもは仕事で疲れてるから、そういった食事でも特に文句は言わない。ズボラってのもあると思うが、この家の維持費は、みんなねぇさんが働いたお金でやりくりされてるし、勿論俺の学費、食費、小遣いもそうだ。多少「めんどくさい」っていって食事が簡略されるのは仕方が無いことだし、俺も**それ**を強制しないようにしている。

Some sort of translation of the whole sentence:

> "It couldn't be helped that she's saying "it's a bother" and as a result
>   our meal is simplified, and I'm trying to not force her to do
>   it(しっかりとした料理) too."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the effort of making it sound more natural in written English, I would translate it as

> I guess saying "it's too much trouble" and thus we have a simplified meal can't really be helped, and I'm trying to avoid forcing her to do it anyway.

I believe you are right, that それ in this sentence indeed refers to 料理を作ること.